# Highcharts Column type visualization: multiple data points for the same Xaxis label

Tags: json, highcharts, visualization

I have this simple json document:

```
var data = [
{
   "x": "a",
   "y": 2
 }, 
{
   "x": "b",
   "y": 8
}, 
{
   "x": "c",
   "y": 4
}, 
{
   "x": "d",
   "y": 15
 }]
```

I can visualize it using Highcharts (see my [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/starz10de/6nwxh256/)). However, I am interested to visualize multiple data points for the same Xaxis label but it doesn't work using my code in [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/starz10de/6nwxh256/) e.g.,:

```
var data = [
    {
       "x": "a",
       "y": [2,3,7]
     }, 
    {
       "x": "b",
       "y": [8,2,1]
    }, 
    {
       "x": "c",
       "y": [4,2,9]
    }, 
    {
       "x": "d",
       "y": [15,10,4]
     }]
```

How I can update my code so it take multiple data point for the same Xaxis label into account.

Comment: What is the question here? It is not clear to me after looking at the question and the attached fiddle.

Comment: I updated my question

Answer (score 0):

Simply split your data into three series and create `categories` array.

API Reference:
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.categories

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/2ar1k6vu/

Comment: I am aware of this solution. However,  as I mentioned I am interested to adapt my solution (because of other tasks requirements) which already work for single data point.